# Latest MiKTeX update breaks XeLaTeX + fleqn

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xetex, equations, miktex

I updated the MiKTeX on my system two days ago. After that, compiling my codes using XeLaTeX gives the following error:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fleqn.clo"
File: fleqn.clo 2015/03/31 v1.1i Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
\mathindent=\dimen102

! Undefined control sequence.
l.50 \IncludeInRelease
                  {2015/01/01}{\[}{Make \[ robust}%
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\begin{document}
    Hi!
\end{document}
```

I have tried the following:

1. Reinstalled MiKTeX;
2. Refreshed the file name database;
3. Updated all format files;

but all those were to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea on what else I can do?

---

**EDIT:**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.2.18)  18 JUN 2015 00:48
entering extended mode
**Sandbox.tex
(Sandbox.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
```

Comment: What does the initial banner in the `.log` file say? Mine says `LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>`

Comment: your update is incomplete the top of the log will show you are using a 2014 (or earlier) format but you have the files from 2015, you need to regenerate the format

Comment: Recreate the format files.

Comment: @egreg I have added more information from the log file.

Comment: @egreg I have recreated the relevant format files. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is essentially the same as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248794/textsubscript-not-working-anymore-after-update so I'll vote for duplicate.

Comment: @egreg I was going to post the following as an answer: "Simply clicking the "Update Formats" in the "General" tab of MiKTeX options did not work because "XeLaTeX" (together with many other formats) are excluded by default. Navigate to the "Formats" tab and change the default attributes."