# How to make a capital V with a brevis or macron over it?

Tags: symbols, characters, linguistics, tipa

I'm doing linguistics, and I need to show short and long vowels.

[image: Example of the VCC notation with brevis and macron]

The `tipa` package handles vowels with the brevis or macron sign over them, but if I use a capital V `\={V}` or `\u{V}` I don't get a capital V with the sign over it: I get a script lowercase v instead.

Edit: Someone points out that without the `tipa` package, this works fine. I hadn't tried that, so thanks!  But with `tipa`, it still doesn't. See code, compiled with ShareLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

Outside of the \texttt{tipa} IPA environment: \={V}C is equivalent to \u{V}CC.

Within the \texttt{tipa} IPA environment: \textipa{\={V}C is equivalent to \u{V}CC.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\={V}` and `\u{V}` should work (not using `tipa` commands)

Comment: Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: how do you compile your code?

Comment: If you want to continue using `tipa` try `\*`, i.e. `\={\*V}`

Comment: Why would you set `\={V}CC` as argument to `\textipa`? They're not IPA symbols.

Comment: egreg: **tipa**, in addition to IPA symbols, has a large section of accented characters specifically for the use of linguists. Thanks for pointing out that the capital letters work outside it!

Comment: @egreg You probably wouldn't, here. Although `\u{\={\*V}}` and even `\'{\u{\={\*V}}}` both will be produced perfectly by `tipa` but will not work outside it with Computer Modern. However, although they are not IPA symbols, they are phonology symbols and I can certainly imagine cases where you might want to do something like `\u{\*V}X $\to$ \={\*V}` (a mostly fictional, highly simplistic, compensatory lengthening process based on [English 'night'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensatory_lengthening)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to the fact that `tipa` redefines basic letters within its IPA environment, which is triggered by `\textipa{...}`, `{\tipaencoding...}`, or `\begin{IPA}...\end{IPA}` (see section 3.2.1 of the [`tipa` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/tipa/tipa/doc/tipaman.pdf)). As you can see on p. 44 of the manual, a capital `V` within the IPA environment is typeset as ʋ:

[image]

This capital letter problem is Q5 in the FAQ section of the manual (pp. 63-64). Here are three ways around it.

### 1. Use a Unicode IPA font and XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX instead of `tipa`

My top recommendation is to avoid using `tipa` for IPA transcription for the reasons outlined at [Typesetting phonetic symbols: Unicode or tipa?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240621/42880).

Here is a MWE that can be compiled using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (and ShareLaTeX does allow you to pick which compiler to use). I typed all the diacritics directly into my TeX using an [IPA keyboard](http://scripts.sil.org/uniipakeyboard), but you could use an online IPA picker or copy and paste from some other source.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} % loads a math font to match Charis SIL
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % package responsible for font selection in XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
\setmainfont{Charis SIL} % sets the document font to Charis SIL, which you would need to have on your system or loaded into ShareLaTeX

\begin{document}
The equivalence of the medial V̄C and V̆CC sequences in the classical languages has long been recognized. It may in fact be rather more broadly stated than we have done so far. V̄C may be restated as V̄C$_0$, where C$_0$ = any number of consonants, including zero (e.g.\ Latin \emph{diḗi, relā́tus, redā́ctus, redḗmptus}); and V̆CC as V̆C$_2$, where C$_2$ = at least 2 consonants.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### 2. Use `\={}` and `\u{}` outside of the `tipa` IPA environment

Regardless of whether you decide to use a Unicode font with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX or to continue using the `palatino` and `tipa` packages with pdfLaTeX, you can use the standard LaTeX macros `\={}` and `\u{}` for the macron and breve, as long as you do it outside of the `tipa` IPA environment. This is what you showed in your MWE.

### 3. Use the `\*` to access the default C and V within the `tipa` IPA environment

As discussed in section 3.2.4 of the `tipa` manual, `\*` may be used before some letters (including all capital letters) within the IPA environment to escape the environment's redefinitions and print the normal letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

The equivalence of the medial \textipa{\={\*V}\*C} and \textipa{\u{\*V}\*C\*C} sequences in the classical languages has long been recognized. It may in fact be rather more broadly stated than we have done so far. \textipa{\={\*V}\*C} may be restated as \textipa{\={\*V}\*C}$_0$, where \textipa{\*C}$_0$ = any number of consonants, including zero (e.g.\ Latin \textsl{\textipa{di\'{\={e}}i, rel\'{\={a}}tus, red\'{\={a}}ctus, red\'{\={a}}mptus}}); and \textipa{\u{\*V}\*C\*C} as \textipa{\u{\*V}\*C}$_2$, where \textipa{\*C}$_2$ = at least 2 consonants.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this works with the default Computer Modern font, but it is not possible to use `tipa` and get IPA output that matches the Palatino font you had in your MWE (below, the Latin words appear in `tipa` Computer Modern lookalike font, and they cannot be slanted because Palatino doesn't have a slant style).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % for Palatino-looking math
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

The equivalence of the medial \textipa{\={\*V}\*C} and \textipa{\u{\*V}\*C\*C} sequences in the classical languages has long been recognized. It may in fact be rather more broadly stated than we have done so far. \textipa{\={\*V}\*C} may be restated as \textipa{\={\*V}\*C}$_0$, where \textipa{\*C}$_0$ = any number of consonants, including zero (e.g.\ Latin \textsl{\textipa{di\'{\={e}}i, rel\'{\={a}}tus, red\'{\={a}}ctus, red\'{\={a}}mptus}}); and \textipa{\u{\*V}\*C\*C} as \textipa{\u{\*V}\*C}$_2$, where \textipa{\*C}$_2$ = at least 2 consonants.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, much more comprehensive than mine. I'd say, though, `C$_0$` is pretty sinful! :P

Comment: @Au101, what is your preference instead?

Comment: Well, there's `\textsubscript{...}` (obviously best to define an abbreviation if your editor can't help you input this more easily. It actually uses math mode anyway, but it keeps maths and text separate in your code and discourages hopping in and out of math mode as a hack (which admittedly I do as well, `$\to$` for example)). But I think it was the separation of subscript and "subscripted" that struck me as a bit of a cheat, I know it's quicker this way, but I'd definitely recommend something more like $\text{C}_{0}$ if I were to use math mode, because C₀ is a unit.

Comment: This doesn't matter and obviously I upvoted, but I thought I'd mention

Comment: Oh okay, I agree that I would normally use something like `$\text{C}_{0}$`, but since the subscripting wasn't at issue I didn't want to load a package just to provide `\text{}`. I also wanted to avoid potential issues with TeX versions and the availability of `\textsubscript{}` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248794/42880 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1013/42880).

Comment: Holy moley, that's a beautiful answer.  Thank you!

P.S. I notice you completed the sentence in the sample correctly. Either good guesswork, or you have a copy of Allen 1973.

Comment: @SteveRapaport Yes it is, don't forget that if this answer helped you the most you can "accept" it by clicking on the tick next to the answers. This will award Jason Zentz 15 reputation points and you 2. It will also mark the question as answered. This does not by any means close the question, but it's good to know the problem has been solved. It also takes the accepted answer to the top, so other users can see the answer which best answered the question for you first. This is not always the best or most popular answer, but 9 times out of 10 ...

Answer (score 2):

## `\={\*V} \u{\*V}`

If you would like to continue using `tipa`, you can use the command `\*` to get `tipa` to print a literal capital letter, instead of reading it as a short cut. For example, as you know, `V` in the IPA environment is a shorthand for `\textscriptv`

[image]

To get an actual V, we have `\*V`:

```
\begin{IPA}
  \*V \textbf{\*V} \textsl{\*V} \={\*V}
\end{IPA}
```

[image]